# SearchApi.cs throws exception:The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search

i created new search service application in sharepoint 2013 farm and search service not working fine, in uls logs i found below errors

SearchApi.cs throws exception:The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component 
'f0c9f633-9b91-476d-bd57-7eb8cd70e21a' in search application 'Search_Service_test' is in a good state and try again.

GetProperty failed with exception 'System.InvalidOperationException: The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. 
Verify that the administration component '' in search application 'Search_Service_test' is in a good state and try again.
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi..ctor(SearchServiceApplication application)
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.get_SearchApi()
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.RebalancerUtil.GetPropertyWriteDefaultIfNotFound(SearchServiceApplication ssa, String propertyName, Int32 defaultValue)'

PS C:\Files> $si = Get-SPServiceInstance 99384b9b-8517-44c5-a880-64323ccdcd56
PS C:\Files> $si

TypeName    : SharePoint Server Search
Description : Index content and serve search queries
Id          : 99384b9b-8517-44c5-a880-64323ccdcd56
Server      : SPServer Name=WFE1
Service     : SearchService Name=OSearch15
Role        : None
Status      : Online

```
searchApp  = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name "Search_Service_test"
```

Write-Host -ForegroundColor white Initializing the administration component
$searchInstance = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Local
$searchApp | Get-SPEnterpriseSearchAdministrationComponent | Set-SPEnterpriseSearchAdministrationComponent -SearchServiceInstance $searchInstance
$admin = ($searchApp | Get-SPEnterpriseSearchAdministrationComponent)
Write-Host -ForegroundColor white Waiting for the admin component to be initialized
foreach($i in 1..120)
{
  sleep 1;
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor white .
  if ($admin.Initialized)
  {
    break
  }
}
  if ($admin.Initialized)
  {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Administration component initialized properly"
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Administration component failed to initialize after 2 mins"
  }

fter that i have errors found in ULS logs

Content Plugin can not be initialized - list of CSS addresses is not set.

Event 2548 (category: Crawler:Content Plugin, product: SharePoint Server Search) is considered as spam. Current number of events suppressed: 816
Failed to extract required parameter FastConnector:ContentDistributor, hr=0x80070002  [pluginconfig.cpp:81]  search\native\gather\plugins\contentpi\pluginconfig.cpp
ConnectionString: 'Data Source=SQL_2013;Initial Catalog=Search_test;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15'    Partition: NULL ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15

service status:

Search Application Topology

Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running